# Matching array indices in Arraylist with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a arraylist. I want to matching arrays and add last column uuid. To do this, the 2nd and 3rd indices in the array must be the same. They can be equal to 2 -> 3 or 3-> 2.

I want to explain this with an example.

```
import uuid as id

test1 = [['412', '413', 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'indian'],
         ['412', '414', 'AAAAA', 'CCCCC', 'indian'],
         ['413', '415', 'BBBBB', 'DDDDD', 'indian'],
         ['413', '415', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFF', 'indian'],
         ['413', '414', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'indian'],
         ['414', '415', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'indian'],
         ['416', '417', 'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'indian']]

x = str(id.uuid4())[:8]
```

append x values last of array

Here, if AAAAA will find its value in all other series, it will match but it does not necessarily have AAAAA. BBBBB can also be. It doesn't matter whether it's on the 2nd or 3rd indices.

Must be output

```
test1 = [['412', '413', 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'indian', 'bb5c11ed'], # same_1
         ['412', '414', 'AAAAA', 'CCCCC', 'indian', 'bb5c11ed'], # same_1
         ['413', '415', 'BBBBB', 'DDDDD', 'indian', 'bb5c11ed'], # same_1
         ['413', '415', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFF', 'indian', 'c47c394e'], # same_2
         ['413', '414', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'indian', 'bb5c11ed'], # same_1
         ['414', '415', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'indian', 'bb5c11ed'], # same_1
         ['416', '417', 'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'indian', 'c47c394e']] # same_2
```

I know I couldn't explain it very well. If you ask where you don't understand, I can help you.

Comment: So the row with `'CCCCC', 'DDDDD'` matches the row with `'AAAAA', 'BBBBB'` because there's also a row with `'AAAAA', 'CCCCC'`?

Comment: yes but 'AAAAA', 'CCCCC' match with  'CCCCC', 'DDDDD' because in have 'CCCCC'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) solution for this (a.k.a Union-Find).

Here is a simple implementation of a Disjoint Set node:

```
import uuid

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rank = 1
        self.parent = self
        self.key = str(uuid.uuid4())  # this is specific to your needs

    def find(self):
        if self.parent != self:
            self.parent = self.parent.find()
        return self.parent

    def union(self, b):
        a = self.find()
        b = b.find()
        if a.rank > b.rank:
            a, b = b, a
        a.parent = b
        b.rank = max(b.rank, 1 + a.rank)
```

Once you have such an implementation of disjoint sets, the main algorithm is quite straightforward:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def addcolumn(data):
    nodes = defaultdict(Node)

    # labels in the same row belong to the same set:
    for row in data:
        nodes[row[2]].union(nodes[row[3]])

    # append the set's key to each row:
    for row in data:
        row.append(nodes[row[2]].find().key)
```

Here is an example run:

```
test1 = [
    ['412', '413', 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'indian'],
    ['412', '414', 'AAAAA', 'CCCCC', 'indian'],
    ['413', '415', 'BBBBB', 'DDDDD', 'indian'],
    ['413', '415', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFF', 'indian'],
    ['413', '414', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'indian'],
    ['414', '415', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'indian'],
    ['416', '417', 'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'indian']
]

addcolumn(test1)

print(test1)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['412', '413', 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'indian', '86c7763e-b7ba-44f9-912b-c5227fde94c1'],
    ['412', '414', 'AAAAA', 'CCCCC', 'indian', '86c7763e-b7ba-44f9-912b-c5227fde94c1'],
    ['413', '415', 'BBBBB', 'DDDDD', 'indian', '86c7763e-b7ba-44f9-912b-c5227fde94c1'],
    ['413', '415', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFF', 'indian', 'a0427da3-b3d3-4ca8-a5a1-7eb42cf81d97'],
    ['413', '414', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'indian', '86c7763e-b7ba-44f9-912b-c5227fde94c1'],
    ['414', '415', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'indian', '86c7763e-b7ba-44f9-912b-c5227fde94c1'],
    ['416', '417', 'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'indian', 'a0427da3-b3d3-4ca8-a5a1-7eb42cf81d97']
]
```

Comment: Awesome, i checked and it works perfectly. I was lost in for loops. thank you with all my heart.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read the question.

You have a graph, with vertices `AAAAA, BBBBB, CCCCC` etc. Each record defines the edge, and each edge in the same connected component shall get the same uuid.

Now the problem reduces to finding the connected components. There is a number of [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms) to solve it.

Comment: actually, when I look at the problem, I think it can be solved in a simpler way.

Comment: I am all ears. What could be simpler?